# Classification and computation of the entanglements of pairs of planar curves

Tags: curves, computable-analysis

Let  $C$ is the set of continuous $f:[0;1]\to \mathbb R^2$ with $\|f\|=\max_t\|f(t)\|$. For $f,g\in C$ let $(f,g)\in E$ iff $\{f(0),f(1)\}\cap {\rm Range}(g)=\emptyset$ and $\{g(0),g(1)\}\cap {\rm Range}(f)=\emptyset$. Let  $(f,g)\sim (f',g')$ iff $H(0)=(f,g)$ and $H(1)=(f',g')$ for some continuous $H:[0;1]\to E$. Has someone considered such a setting / characterized the equivalence classes (types of entanglement) /computed a normal form (with minimal number of intersections)?
Related to: http://arxiv.org/abs/2009.09964

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "types of entanglement" in this context?

Comment: I think that a "type of entanglement" is just another name for an equivalence class for his relation.